# Ubuntu x64 installation

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

So my computer tells me that the processor is 64-bit capable, but it has 32-bit Windows Vista installed on it. Would it be okay to install 64-bit Ubuntu alongside 32-bit Windows or would it have big negative effects on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

that will work fine. I did the same on my Asus 1201n EEE PC. :)

If you got less than 2Gb RAM I wouldn't install 64-bit since it uses slightly more RAM, not much but slightly. It depends on how much RAM you normally uses, like do you have 15 tabs opened in Chrome at the same time, then 32-bit might be slightly better. But this is a corner case and in most cases you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

there wouldn't be any problem for doing this , I have 32 bit windows 7 and UBUNTU 64 bit alongside it . I have a desktop pc with this combination and a hp probook laptop too .

if you want to do this I recommend you to have different partition for UBUNTU and your windows , I would not suggest you to install ubuntu on the same partition that windows is , and make sure you have more than 2 gigabyte RAM .